# Ubuntu all screwy after dist-upgrade. How do I revert the damage?

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, troubleshooting, dist-upgrade

After last night's kernel upgrade I'm getting the following symptoms:

After restarting computer several times.

- One of my screens (always the same one) is split down the middle. Not always in the same place, and sometimes shows "trails".
- Unity desktop half-loads and then doesn't respond to *any* command. The mouse moves but nothing is clickable.
- Xmonad desktop responds (I'm on Xmonad desktop right now, using the second screen).

Curiously:

- During one of my boots, Ubuntu brought up the Grub menu. I chose "ubuntu" option and suddenly everything worked fine. I restarted the computer again, and everything is screwy again.
- I've tried to bring up the Grub menu again, but pressing **shift** during boot process makes my computer shut off instantly and restart.

How do I revert the damage caused by the dist-upgrade?

Comment: Do you have an ATI or nVidia graphic card? What model? Have you installed some driver?

Comment: kernel update was the problem. I apt-get autoremoved it and it's back to normal. -- To skip a kernel version, I just have to wait till the next kernel upgrade and apt-get dist-upgrade then, right?

Comment: **First**: Don't put the **answer** into the **question**, you should [answer your own question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3004/62483). **Second:** If you do an `apt-get dist-upgrade` then your kernel version will be updated. If you want to keep a specific version you can *remove the new one*, just like you did.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for future reference:

Kernel update was the problem. Removing the newly updated kernel solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove linux-image-3.5.0-22.generic
```